# TreeView plus-minus icon size

Tags: winapi, fonts, treeview, icons

In [TreeView fontsize - Custom Draw or Owner Draw](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14489358/treeview-fontsize-custom-draw-or-owner-draw/14489696#14489696), I learned how to change the font size of the text in a TreeView control. Just using `WM_SETFONT` message.

But when I increase the font size, the plus-minus sign is not changed at the same time.

How can I set the plus-minus sign icon size at runtime, according to the item size (which is determined by the font size).

Here is the picture:

[image]

Comment: I don't think there's any way to change this, as it's defined by the current visual style and not based on the font size.

Comment: If it's not changable via the state images, I doubt it's exposed via custom drawing so you may need to resort to full owner drawing.